# PBI desktop YTD function

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop, dashboard

I am trying to calculate a YTD for a Budget that has values until end of year, but I want only to show me YTD up to where there's values for Actuals, for instance in the table below there are values for actuals up to March, so I need my budget YTD to be the sum of Jan to March. I tried many things but I keep getting circular dependency. I was able to create a measure to get the max date for actuals (3/22/2023), but can't use it to limit the YTD of budgets to that date. Any help will be appreciated!
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than trying to do a YTD calculation, it may be more optimal to [CALCULATE](https://dax.guide/calculate/) the sum of Budget Value on the min/max dates for Scenario = "Budget".

[image]

```
Budget YTD =
VAR _min_date =
    CALCULATE ( MIN ( 'Table'[Date] ), 'Table'[Scenario] = "Actuals" )
VAR _max_date =
    CALCULATE ( MAX ( 'Table'[Date] ), 'Table'[Scenario] = "Actuals" )
RETURN
    CALCULATE (
        SUM ( 'Table'[Value] ),
        'Table'[Date] >= _min_date,
        'Table'[Date] <= _max_date,
        'Table'[Scenario] = "Budget"
    )
```